# Creating content with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, arraylist

I've created a portion of my content through using jQuery to make the same content for each item in my list. It has all worked perfectly except for the last entry. For some reason it acts weird.

An input field is created for each entry that only accepts 2 characters. I have an error script that will parse the entry and see if it's valid. I am only accepting numbers below 61 in this case. All the inputs work except for the last entry.

Additionally, the labels for the 3 inputs created are not putting focus on the respected input value for this entry.

My problem is I don't know why the last entry doesn't work whereas the others will. Can someone explain?

Below are a few functions used.

Populate.js (Used to create content from list)

```
var $parent = $('div#heroes');
var prestige = '<option value="0">None</option><option value="1">Prestige 1</option><option value="2">Prestige 2</option><option value="3">Prestige 3</option><option value="4">Prestige 4</option><option value="5">Prestige 5</option>'
$.each(heroes, function(index,value) {
    $div = $('<div id="hero' + index + '"></div>');
    $div.append('<h6>' + value + '</h6>');
    $div.append('<span id="active"><input type="checkbox" id="isActive' + index + '" /><label for="isActive' + index + '">Is Active?</label></span>');
    $div.append('<span id="level"><label for="level' + index + '">Level:&nbsp;</label><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" id="level' + index + '" /></span>');
    $div.append('<span id="prestige"><label for="prestige' + index + '">Prestige:&nbsp;</label><select id="prestige' + index + '">' + prestige + '</select></span>');

    $parent.append($div);
});
```

errors.js (Parses the input value and prints the error if not a integer below 61)

```
$.each(heroes, function(index,value){
    $('input#level' + index).change(function() {
        var val = $('input#level' + index).val();
        if(val > 60) {
            alertify.log("Hero " + value + " cannot be above Level 60!", "", 0);
            $('#level' + index).addClass('error');
        } else if( isNumeric(val) ) {
            if( $('#level' + index).hasClass('error') ) {
                $('#level' + index).removeClass('error');
            }
        } else {
            alertify.log("Only numbers are accepted.");
            $('#level' + index).addClass('error');
        }
    });
});

function isNumeric(num){
    return !isNaN(num);
}
```

The list used:

```
var heroes = ["Black Panther","Black Widow","Cable","Captain America","Colossus","Cyclops","Daredevil","Deadpool",/*"Doctor Strange",*/"Emma Frost",
"Gambit","Ghost Rider","Hawkeye","Hulk","Human Torch","Iron Man","Jean Grey",/*"Juggernaut",*/"Loki","Luke Cage",/*"Magneto","Moon Knight",*/"Ms Marvel",
"Nightcrawler",/*"Nova","Psylocke",*/"Punisher","Rocket Raccoon",/*"Silver Surfer",*/"Scarlet Witch","Spider-Man","Squirrel Girl",/*"Star-Lord",*/"Storm",
/*"Sue Storm",*/"Thing","Thor","Wolverine"/*,"Venom"*/];
```

You can view the page at http://spedwards.cz.cc/new.html

I am still accepting answers. I am stumped to why this isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out my problem. I'm using the bx-slider plugin and it creates a clone of the last element before the first and a clone of the first, after the last. So my function was getting the clone.
All I had to do was add `:not(.bx-clone)` to the selector.

So instead of `$('input#level' + index);` it changed to `$('input#level' + index + ':not(.bx-clone)');`